# Real time tracking in google map

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, google-maps

I already wrote a android apps to upload the lat and long to MySQL database(updated every 2min).

now, i have no idea how to show the real time location on Google map in the website(php,javascript,html)
which means how to dynamic update the Google map markers every 2 min [get the last two minutes records from MySQL database 
and show the markers(update or disappear)]

and after i click the marker, it should show the info[get from mysql database(not important point because it same with static Google map!?]

just like this: http://traintimes.org.uk/map/tube/

I just know how to do when i just get 1 time (Static Google map!?) with my limited knowledge.

I have already searched same question in stack overflow and google
but i am sorry i still no idea how to do it because of my lack of knowledge.

[Real time Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545899/real-time-google-map)

anyone could give me some tutorial website or suggestion?

At last, thank all of you 
and
I still a learner of English,I am sorry about any wrong grammar.

Comment: thx all.I already finished it by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626134/google-maps-v3-updating-markers-periodically

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Real-time Tracking Geo Latitude/Longitude on a Map

You are looking to update coordinate entities (lat/lon position) on a map (google maps or otherwise) in real-time as the updates occur.  Here is a blog post that may get you started in the right direction: http://blog.pubnub.com/streaming-geo-coordinates-from-mongodb-to-your-iphone-app-with-pubnub-using-websocket-sdk/ - this uses MongoDB and Ruby rather than PHP and MySQL.  However it will be easy to get things setup in this case with a real-time map in PHP and MySQL on an HTML page with the following details. And there is a video too: https://vimeo.com/60716860

### Using MySQL to Trigger Update in Real-time

First you'll want to use either MySQL triggers to push the Lat/Long coords - [Invoke pusher when mysql has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474012/invoke-pusher-when-mysql-has-changed?answertab=active#tab-top) - this uses MySQL Triggers

Or as an alternative you may want to use PHP directly to invoke the push signal using a PHP push SDK as follows: https://github.com/pubnub/php#php-push-api

```
$pubnub->publish(array(
    'channel' => 'live_map_coords',
    'message' => array( 12.3482, 8.3344 )
));
```

### Receiving The Push Message in JavaScript and Showing the Updates on a Map

```
<script src=//pubnub.a.ssl.fastly.net/pubnub-3.4.5.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){

    PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key : 'demo'
    }).subscribe({
        channel  : 'live_map_coords',
        callback : function(lat_lon) { alert(lat_lon) }
    });

})();</script>
```

Once you have an `map.html` page with the above code in it, you can change the `alert(lat_log)` message popup with drawing coords on a map.  Here is a fully working map drawn example using `D3` JavaScript SVG rendering Framework:  https://github.com/stephenlb/pubnub-mongo-pipe/blob/master/phone/map.html

> **NOTE:** This is only a starting point and provides you with references on getting started to make it easy and simple, yet flexible based on the direction you will be taking your app.

### Next Steps to Piece Together the Real-time Geo Map

You will next want to do the following to complete the process and join together all the separate components listed here.

1. Modify the `map.html` page for your purposes to display always-visible dots.  Note that in the video the dots are temporary beacons that display and vanish rapidly.  You'll want to make them persist on the map.  This is basically the *"Make it look the way you want it"* step.
2. Decide how and when you want to trigger the TCP Socket Push events from PHP or MySQL directly.  **I'd recommend the PHP approach**.