# How can I use aftership tracking facility in my website in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, tracking

I am trying to add the features of tracking the product that was bought from my site . I want to give the user detail about their product delivery and location of it like done by aftership. How can i implement it in my web site? How can i initiate it?

Comment: I think this answer help you, [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16466545)

Comment: @PareshBarad I was asking to integrate aftership in my website though. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow following step for aftership tracking integration.

1. Login to your AfterShip account.
2. Visit SETTINGS > API
3. Give your api-key a name and click Generate
4. integrate PHP sdk for aftership [Aftership SDK](https://github.com/AfterShip/aftership-sdk-php)
5. You can install SDK by `composer require aftership/aftership-php-sdk` command.
6. Please follow git document instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer